# How to define Airflow DAG/task that shouldn't run periodically

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

The goal is pretty simple: I need to create a DAG for a manual task that should not run periodically, but only when admin presses the "Run" button. Ideally without a need to switch "unpause" and "pause" the DAG (you know someone will surely forget to pause).

So far I only came with `schedule_interval="0 0 30 2 *"` (30th Feb hopefully never occurs), but there must be a better way!

Is there?

Comment: Made me laugh with the 30th of feb fix.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html), you can set the scheduler preset to `None` (Don’t schedule, use for exclusively “externally triggered” DAGs). Also, you can set it to `@once` if schedule once and only once.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't notice that. Shame on me;) Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Set `schedule_interval=None`.

For example:

```py
from airflow import models

with models.DAG(
    'Your DAG',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1)
) as dag:
...
```